# Backbone js : Is POST call with request body null possible. Not empty json {}

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a REST API with json form where request body is optional. The usual save modal sends "{}" . Is this even possible with backbone js. Postman allows to pass empty

Updated: Making call with modal.save()

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

Comment: Without knowing specifically how you're sending the request, it's difficult to answer. That said (almost) anything can be overridden in BackboneJS, so I'd say the answer is more than likely yes.

Comment: I have updated the post here. Backbone's save is used to make POST call

Comment: *"The usual save modal sends "{}"* when it should be sending current JSON representation of model attributes as far as I understand, if there are no attributes then attributes is `{}`, not `null`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to override the model's [`toJSON`](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to return `null` in some condition.